# what does url_for('.outbound', _external=True) means?

Tags: python, flask

I have a python Twilio code like this(Click to Call method in twilio):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
#from flask import render_template
#from flask import request
from flask import url_for

from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from twilio.rest import Client

app = Flask(__name__)

# Voice Request URL
@app.route('/call')
def call():
    # Get phone number we need to call
    phone_number = request.form.get('phoneNumber', None)

    try:
        twilio_client = Client(app.config['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'],
                               app.config['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
    except Exception as e:
        msg = 'Missing configuration variable: {0}'.format(e)
        return jsonify({'error': msg})

    try:
        twilio_client.calls.create(from_=app.config['TWILIO_CALLER_ID'],
                                   to=phone_number,
                                   url=url_for('.outbound', _external=True))
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(e)
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

    return jsonify({'message': 'Call incoming!'})


@app.route('/outbound', methods=['POST'])
def outbound():
    response = VoiceResponse()

    response.say("Thank you for contacting our sales department. If this "
                 "click to call application was in production, we would "
                 "dial out to your sales team with the Dial verb.",
                 voice='alice')

    response.number("+16518675309")

    return str(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When i try run run this from browser by calling : http://localhost:5000/call
i am getting ERROR:  Unable to create record: Url is not a valid url:

How to call the Outbound function in the url and start the conversation between two people.

Comment: Please check the API of [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `url_for('.outbound', _external=True)` you should use `url_for('outbound')`. The [docs linked by stamaimer](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.url_for) say:

> In case blueprints are active you can shortcut references to the same blueprint by prefixing the local endpoint with a dot (.).

You do not need a dot at the beginning. Check how [url building is handled in flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#url-building).

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: @tomasantunes I've updated them. Thanks for pointing out.